# Is there a way to automatically have a #define reproduced in each source file

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, macros, c-preprocessor

I'd like the following to appear in every source file in my Visual C++ 2005 solution:

```
  #define DEBUG_NEW new(_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
  #define new DEBUG_NEW
```

Is there a way of doing this without manually copying it in? Compiler option?

Answer (score 5):

The command line option [`/D`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8(VS.71).aspx) can be used to define preprocessor symbols. I don't know, though, whether it can also be used to define macros with arguments, but it should be an easy matter to test that.

Edit: Failing that, the [`/FI` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84(VS.71).aspx) ("force include") should allow you to do what you want. Quoting the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84(VS.71).aspx):

> This option has the same effect as specifying the file with double quotation marks in an #include directive on the first line of every source file [...] .

You can then put your `#define`s in that forced include file.

Comment: Unfortunately both of these suggestions result in lots of errors.

I'm trying to track down memory leaks using the suggestion here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/5a98b72e-c927-4f4b-9441-8a73575dfb10

Comment: What error messages, exactly? Are you defining _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC?

If that's not the problem, you may be running into the problem described here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619467/macro-to-replace-c-operator-new

Comment: This approach will not work, if file includes header, in which placementnew is used. Reason is that DEBUG_NEW macro is incompatible with placement new, and that file is treated as included at first line. In practice problem will be with STL and Boost headers.

Answer (score 4):

I'd advise against using this `#define`. Re-defining `new` is not portable and if you do it in this way then you prevent anything subsequently using a placement `new` from working. If you 'force' this `#define` before a file's manually `#include`s take effect then you risk incompatibilities between library header files and their source files and you will get 'surprise' errors in library files that use placement `new` (frequently template/container classes).

If you are going to redefine `new`, then make it explicit and leave it in the source.

Answer (score 2):

You could insert that `#define` into stdafx.h or common.h or any other header file that gets included into each source file.

Answer (score 1):

> Compiler option?

Yes, you can customize a list of `define`s in the project properties (either under “Preprocessor” or “Advanced,” as far as I remember). These `define`s will be present in each source file.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the `#define`s into an `h` file, but without putting the `#ifndef` guard in the `h` file.  Then `#include` the file in each of your source files.

I am not endorsing redefining `new`, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You can just define your own global new operator somewhere in your code and compile it conditionally. Do not forget to include all 4 variations of new( plain and array one with and without nothrow) and two variations of delete(plain and array one). There is a whole chapter on the matter in my copy of Effective C++, Third Edition (Chapter 8)

```
#ifdef MYDEBUG
void* operator new(std::size_t size) { <your code here> }
void operator delete(void* p) { <your code here> }
#endif
```