# Use of new operator -compiled error C2661: 'CObject::operator new' : no overloaded function takes 4 arguments (Multiple Inheritance)

Tags: c++, mfc, compiler-errors, multiple-inheritance, new-operator

I have the below class in header file

```
class CodeListSqlGenerator : public ICodeListSqlGenerator,public CDialog


{
    ........
public:
CodeListSqlGenerator(IIntelligentCodeListUpgraderParameter *i_intelligent_codelist_upgrader_parameter);
}
```

When I use a new operator in .cpp file to create an object of type CodeListSqlGenerator

```
ICodeListSqlGenerator *CreateCodeListSqlGeneratorInterface(IIntelligentCodeListUpgraderParameter *i_intelligent_codelist_upgrader_parameter)
{
ICodeListSqlGenerator *i_codelist_sql_generator = new CodeListSqlGenerator(i_intelligent_codelist_upgrader_parameter);
return i_codelist_sql_generator;
}
```

I'm get getting the below when compiled error C2661: 'CObject::operator new' : no overloaded function takes 4 arguments
How do I rectify this error?
Thanks in advance -Athreya

Comment: What do the constructor definitions in the class hierarchy look like?  This error can be caused by an incorrect base initialization in an initializer list.

Comment: Or, more likely, you are using MFC and have mixed up debug and non-debug settings.

Comment: @James McNellis- Constructor definition.. public:
 CodeListSqlGenerator(IIntelligentCodeListUpgraderParameter *i_intelligent_codelist_upgrader_parameter);
}

Comment: @James McNellis - Yes I'm using MFC, can you brief me little more on debug and non-debug settings what I need to change

Comment: I cannot, but there are other people who can.  I just vaguely remember having had this issue before once; what I did to resolve it I do not remember.

Comment: Possibly something about a DEBUG_NEW macro interfering with every other definition of new.

Comment: Like discussed here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326656/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-have-a-define-reproduced-in-each-source-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326656/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-have-a-define-reproduced-in-each-source-file/1326779#1326779)

Comment: Do you still get the same error if you write `#undef new` right before the line of code which is causing the error?

Comment: @AAdam Rosenfield and Bo Persso - No Im no longer getting the error, when #undef new thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEBUG_NEW macro has to be change,. check whether you have included preprocessor #undef new,
Try to write the #undef new before the new keyword

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to create an ICodeListSqlGenerator object using the CodeListSqlGenerator constructor. This cannot be done, as ICodeListSqlGenerator already has its own constructor. However, a CodeListSqlGenerator object IS A ICodeListSqlGenerator, so you can create a CodeListSqlGenerator object and return the pointer to it as a ICodeListSqlGenerator pointer.

Comment: I'm not trying to create ICodeListSqlGenerator object,
ICodeListSqlGenerator *i_codelist_sql_generator = new CodeListSqlGenerator(i_intelligent_codelist_upgrader_parameter);
Creates reference of CodeListSqlGenerator object

Comment: Umm... you do realize it actually creates the object and returns a pointer to the new object, right?

Comment: Yes, an object reference rite  ICodeListSqlGenerator is an Interface so I won't be able to create it object