# How to override new in C++ when using the Boost libraries?

Tags: c++, boost, operator-overloading, new-operator, delete-operator

I've overridden the global new and delete operators for my project, but I'm having trouble making it all work with the Boost libraries. I've implemented the solution here: [Macro to replace C++ operator new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619467/macro-to-replace-c-operator-new) to get around the problem that I was having with multiple overloads. However, the Boost libraries have an annoying habit of using `operator new` rather than simply using `new` leaving the preprocessor to expand:

`::operator new(n);`

to:

`::operator (__file__ = "someFile.cpp", __line__ = 123) && 0 ? NULL : new(n);`

Is it possible to write another macro to remove these "undesired" expansions? For example, I tried writing:

`#define (operator (file, line) && 0 ? NULL :) operator new`

But apparently parenthesis are not allowed in the identifier portion of the macro. How can I use the Boost libraries, but still get my memory allocation tracking?

Comment: I think modifying Boost might be a heck of a lot easier than dealing with this mess. It's open-source and header-only, after all.

Comment: @Mehrdad What about upgrades?

Comment: @curiousguy: Just re-apply your changes after the upgrade... it's not that hard. A diff/patch or a regex might do (not sure if a regex will work, but worth a try).

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes, but... it seems risky. I would only do that if it was absolutely needed. (F.ex. to correct a bug in some library.)

Comment: The "annoying habit" is because `operator new` has different behaviour to a new-expression, and sometimes, especially in low-level library code, that's the behaviour you need. You'll find the same "habit" in the Standard Library implementation, since allocators use `operator new` to allocate raw memory.

Answer (score 1):

A good answer depends on what you need this *for*, but apparently it's to reduce the time spent on debugging (by having information about which blocks were allocated where).

Then, first of all, the best general way to reduce the time spent on debugging allocations and deallocations, is to use *smart pointers* such as `std::shared_ptr`. Let smart pointers manage your deallocations automatically and correctly. That can really reduce time spent on debugging.

That said, one way to get the info you want is to *be explicit* about it. In your code, write e.g. `TRACKING_NEW` instead of just `new`, in `new`-expressions. Then define `TRACKING_NEW` accordingly.

Don’t define a macro called `new`.

Apart from the formal problem (you have UB if you include any standard header after that), it is almost guaranteed to trap you. So, do define e.g. `TRACKING_NEW` if you find that it is still desirable after changing the code to use smart pointers. But don’t define a macro called `new`.